# Reading csv file in pyspark from google docs link

Tags: dataframe, pyspark

I have a view only csv in google docs:

```
url = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/random_link'
```

I want to read it in pyspark dataframe, any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

make sure that you have been given permission to access the file via the link. then the below-written code will work.

```
url="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/random_link"
import pandas as pd
df=spark.createDataFrame(pd.read_csv(url))
```

Comment: getting following error:
  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 899, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.read
  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 914, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_low_memory
  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 968, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_rows
  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 955, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._tokenize_rows
  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 2172, in pandas._libs.parsers.raise_parser_error
pandas.errors.ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 6, saw 2

Answer (score 1):

```
!pip install -U -q PyDrive
import pandas as pd

from pydrive.auth import GoogleAuth
from pydrive.drive import GoogleDrive
from google.colab import auth
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials
```

#### Authenticate and create the PyDrive client.

```
auth.authenticate_user()
gauth = GoogleAuth()
gauth.credentials = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()
drive = GoogleDrive(gauth)
```

#### Sharabel link of dataset

```
link = 'https://drive.google.com/file/d/1T4K69xTfum0Xb69YxqOfgIsYFK0IUaZw/view?usp=sharing'
```

#### To get the id part of the file

```
id = link.split("/")[-2]
downloaded = drive.CreateFile({'id':id})
downloaded.GetContentFile('london_crime_by_isoa.csv')
```

#### First reading dataset from pandas

```
df = pd.read_csv('london_crime_by_isoa.csv')
```

#### Now we create spark dataframe

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("Analyze London crime data").getOrCreate()

data = spark.createDataFrame(df)
data.printSchema()
```